# Hiding divs with overflow

Tags: css, css-position, overflow

I want the blue square to be visible and red square to be hidden below the blue square. Blue and red should not overlap, they need to be ordered one after the other. But my CSS is not doing this. What am I missing?

```js
document.getElementById('startAnim').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('red').classList.add('animate');
});
```

```css
#background {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #3CF;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  border: medium;
}

#blue {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: thin;
  top: 0%;
  border-color: #000;
  border-width: 1px;
}

#red {
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 50%;
  border: thin;
  border-color: #000;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.sq {
  position: absolute;
}

.animate {
  -webkit-animation-name: slidediv;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}


/* Standard syntax */

@keyframes slidediv {
  0% {
    top: 10px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="background">
  <div id="blue" class='sq'></div>
  <div id="red" class='sq'></div>
</div>
<button id="startAnim"> Start </button>
```

Comment: Not sure I understand exactly what you are trying to achieve. In starting frame you want the blue on top of the red, not below it yes? Then when the start button is pressed you want the blue to animate below the red?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated #red top property to 100%. Like below:

```
#red {
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 100%;
  border: thin;
  border-color: #000;
  border-width: 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

what i understood is that you need the red square to be hidden below the blue one, so u can use the z-index to fix this, try my snippet if that's what you are looking for

```js
document.getElementById('startAnim').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('blue').classList.add('animate');
});
```

```css
#background {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #3CF;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  border: medium;
}

#blue {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: thin;
  top: 0%;
  border-color: #000;
  border-width: 1px;
  z-index:7;
}

#red {
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 0%;
  border: thin;
  border-color: #000;
  border-width: 1px;
  z-index:6;
}

.sq {
  position: absolute;
}

.animate {
  -webkit-animation-name: slidediv;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}


/* Standard syntax */

@keyframes slidediv {
  0% {
    top: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="background">
  <div id="blue" class='sq'></div>
  <div id="red" class='sq'></div>
</div>
<button id="startAnim"> Start </button>
```

Comment: Looks like your answer either puts the square on top of each or red is above blue. I need blue to be above red. I have provided a solution below.